# Getting Relative Path Of File Stored in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, filepath, relative-path, absolute-path, web-inf

I'm somewhat of a beginner learning Java.

I'm having trouble with finding the path-file

`readPublicKeyFromFile("C:\Users\myname\workspace\MyProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\Config\My_Public.key");`

for one of my methods:

```
public byte[] encryptData(String data) throws IOException {


        byte[] dataToEncrypt = data.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedData = null;

        try
        {
            PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile("C:\Users\myname\workspace\MyProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\Config\My_Public.key");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + encryptedData);
        }
        catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        System.out.println("--ENCRYPTION COMPLETED--");
        return encryptedData;
    }
```

The file `My_Public.key` is stored in `C:\Users\myname\workspace\MyProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\Config\My_Public.key`in my computer system and in my Eclipse Project hierarchy it is as follows:

```
> MyProject
  > WebContent
     > WEB-INF
        > Config
           > My_Public.key
     > META-INF
```

It **works fine** if I use relative path `"C:/Users/myname/workspace/MyProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/Config/My_Public.key`.
But I don't want to use the relative path `C:/Users/myname/...` since it will not work when I upload my Java web-app online.

I try using some path like:

`readPublicKeyFromFile(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/WEB-INF/Config/My_Public.key"));`

But it gives me this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent\WEB-INF\Config\My_Public.key
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

How can I read from my file:

```
> MyProject
      > WebContent
         > WEB-INF
            > Config
               > My_Public.key //How can I read from this file in the correct path?
         > META-INF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
readPublicKeyFromFile(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Config/My_Public.key"));
```

Comment: Still the same error:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WEB-INF\Config\My_Public.key (The system cannot find the path specified)